# Add video of custom in instant article header wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, instant

I am able to add a video (saved in custom field 'video_url') in instant article, but it is showing on . I need it to appear in  instead of the featured image.

The code which I am using to add video in

```
add_action( 'instant_articles_after_transform_post', function ($ia_post) {
    $instant_article = $ia_post->instant_article;
    $post_id = $ia_post->get_the_id();
    $video_url = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'video_url', true );
    $instant_article->addChild( 
    Facebook\InstantArticles\Elements\Video::create()->withURL($video_url) );
});
```

Comment: the image is shown in body tag i need it on header tag

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be useful. Advanced Custom Fields can be added all over WP including posts, users, taxonomy terms, media, comments, and even custom options pages!

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

For detailed documentation - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/

Comment: I already have a custom field. What I need to do is replace figure tag of featured image with the video link of custom field.

Comment: There is one filter "_wp_post_thumbnail_html()" available - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_post_thumbnail_html/. 
Thread - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250432/custom-field-in-featured-image-for-a-particular-post